# Java Program print student Grade

Tags: java

I wanna Write a program to print out the user's grade ("Excellent if grade is A, Very Good if grade is B, Good if grade is C, Fair if grade is D, Fail if grade is F"). using Switch Statement
But When User input a or b or c or d or f in lowercase Apply the Grade 
I mean I wanna char = A or a Match the Grade "Excellent" 
and char = B or b Match the Grade " Very Good " and so on 
Thanks and I hope to Find a Quick Solution 
I tried this But it doesn't Make anything

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char Grade = 'A';
        switch (Grade)
        {
            case 'A':
                System.out.println("Excellent");
                break;
            case 'B':
                System.out.println("Very Good");
                break;
            case 'C':
                System.out.println("Good");
                break;
            case 'D':
                System.out.println("Fair");
                break;
            case 'F':
                System.out.println("Fail");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways:

1. Multiple `case` statements:

   ```
   switch (Grade) {

       case 'A': 
       case 'a': 
           System.out.println("Excellent");
           break;
       case 'B':
       case 'b':
           System.out.println("Very Good");
           break;
       case 'C':
       case 'c':
           System.out.println("Good");
           break;
       case 'D':
       case 'd':
           System.out.println("Fair");
           break;
       case 'F':
       case 'f':
           System.out.println("Fail");
           break;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Converting the character to upper case:

   ```
   char Grade = 'A';    
   Grade = Character.toUpperCase(Grade);

   switch (Grade) {
    ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Yeah i tried this 2 Ways and I get The Right Result   Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply covert the character entered by the user to either lower case or lower case and compare accordingly.